# WrapGrid and a lot of Images

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have GridView with WrapGrid as ItemTemplate. It looks like:

```
<GridView ItemsSource={Binding MyItemSource}>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <Image Width="250" Height="250">
                  <Image.Source>
                       <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding }" DecodePixelWidth=250/>
                  </Image.Source>
             </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
     </GridView.ItemTemplate>

     <GridView.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <WrapGrid/>
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```

MyItemSource contains Uri's to image files (a lot of Uri's). It works without OutOfMemoryException thanks to virtualization process. However when I decide to scroll "fast and far away" there is a lot of unnecessary loading work for images that are "between" in scrolling area. (a lot of unnecessary cpu, disk and memory usage) I'd like to start loading process when user don't scroll (when user stop scrolls, not loading images which are seen just for a moment while scrolling). Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Windows 8.1 you can tap into the ContainerContentChanging event and control what gets rendered at what time.